# Combining signals but just subscribe when first one changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I want to combine the `rac_signalForControlEvent` on a UIButton with some combined textFields signals like so:

```
    [[[[self.loginButton rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
    combineLatestWith:textFieldsCombinedSignal]
    filter:^BOOL(RACTuple *signals) {
      return ((UIButton *)[signals first]).highlighted;
    }]  subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *signals) {
      if ([signals.second boolValue])
      {
          [self doLogin];
      }
      else
      {
          [self error];
      }
    }];
```

But this way I have to filter for the button highlighted state otherwise the `subscribeNext:` block is getting fired every time some of the textfields change (`textFieldsCombinedSignal`).

I would love to achieve this without having to filter for the highlighted button's state (I'm using ReactiveCocoa to minimize state after all, and I don't feel like this is the proper way to do what I'm trying to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a sequence of button tap and *then* the latest from your combined text field signal, it can be as simple as using `-flattenMap:`:

```
[[[self.loginButton
    rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
    flattenMap:^(id _) {
        return [textFieldsCombinedSignal take:1];
    }]
    subscribeNext:^…];
```

However, from what you've described, this seems like a classic case for `RACCommand`. Both this code, and the original code, allow for the user to double tap the login button and trigger concurrent logins.

Before showing `RACCommand`, I'll make a couple of assumptions about your code. From the name alone, `textFieldsCombinedSignal` it could be a signal that sends a tuple of strings, but in your use it looks like it's actually a validation signal that sends YES/NO. I'll assume the latter and rename it to `loginIsValid`. I'll also assume that `-doLogin` is synchronous for the purpose of this example.

Now to `RACCommand`:

```
self.loginButton.rac_command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithEnabledSignal:loginIsValid signalBlock:^(id _) {
    return [RACSignal defer:^{
        [self doLogin];
        return [RACSignal empty];
    }];
}];
```

What this will do is enable/disable the login button based on the latest value sent on `loginIsValid`. When enabled, a tap on the button will cause `-doLogin` to be called, and the button will become disabled for the duration of the login process, preventing concurrent logins.

Comment: Thanks @dave , but using `RACCommand`: what about handling error in forms (like notifying the user there's some field missing)? `signalBlock` will only be executed as long as button is enabled

Comment: @JoanRomano In that case, skip the enabled signal and use `[RACCommand -initWithSignalBlock:]`. This forfeits some of the automatic button disabling, but still keeps the serial executions. Inside the signal block, return an error signal (e.g. using `+[RACSignal error:]`) if the form isn't valid, otherwise call `-doLogin`. `RACCommand` has an `errors` property which is a signal that sends errors as values, subscribe to it to respond to validation errors in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want to sample the `textFieldsCombinedSignal` whenever the button is tapped. Try using `-sample:`:

```
RACSignal *buttonSignal = [self.loginButton rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[[textFieldsCombinedSignal sample:buttonSignal] subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *combinedTextFields) {
    // do stuff with combinedTextFields
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, this one is working as well but I will vote @dave's as the correct one since it's more clear plus gives the `RACCommand` example.